# How to resolve "SecurityManager: authentication disabled; exception in spark distribution cluster"?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop2

I have created a Spark distribution cluster in Linux (Ubuntu) environment to run Spark submit job. I have 3 machines (m1, s1 and s2; m1 is master, s1 and s2 are slaves machines).

In master Spark and slave Spark directory `../spark/conf/ spark-defaults.conf`, `spark-env.sh`. I have configured everything.

**spark-env.sh**

```
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=198.77.8.7
export SPARK_WORKER_HOST=198.77.8.12
export SPARK_WORKER_HOST=198.77.8.18
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=198.77.8.7
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8
```

**spark-defaults.conf**

```
spark.master yarn
spark.executor.memory 1g
spark.driver.memory 1g
spark.yarn.am.memory 1g
```

Working command is:

> bin/spark-submit --master local[*] --deploy-mode client --class com.x.y.App --executor-memory 15G --executor-cores 2 --driver-memory 15G /home/user/workspace/test.jar

I am getting the output file, but when I run in cluster mode it gives me an exception. The command is:

> bin/spark-submit --master spark://198.47.12.8:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --class com.x.y.App --executor-memory 15G --executor-cores 2 --driver-memory 15G /home/user/workspace/test.jar

Exception:

```
21/01/08 16:51:51 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
21/01/08 16:51:51 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(sys92); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(sys92); groups with modify permissions: Set()
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/01/08 16:51:51 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'Driver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'Driver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:550)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:248)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I checked all 3 systems' `/etc/hosts` files (I think it is not the problem).

**Master-etc/hosts**

```
#127.0.0.1  localhost
#127.0.1.1  mater1

198.77.8.7   mater1
198.77.8.12  slave1
198.77.8.18  slave2
```

**Salve1-etc/hosts**

```
#127.0.0.1  localhost
#127.0.1.1  slave1

198.77.8.7   mater1
198.77.8.12  slave1
198.77.8.18  slave2
```

**Slave2-etc/hosts**

```
#127.0.0.1  localhost
#127.0.1.1  slave2

198.77.8.7   mater1
198.77.8.12  slave1
198.77.8.18  slave2
```

Comment: Did you able to resolve this issue? I am also facing the similar issue. Please let me know if you found the solution or root cause.